# Problems seen in production due to high replication factor

Tags: performance, replication, cassandra

Has anyone run a fully replicated Cassandra cluster in production? We have a business use case that essentially requires the dataset stored by Cassandra to be fully replicated. This would require us to have a RF of N where N is the size of the cluster. I am wondering if anyone has used this configuration before and the problems associated with it. Note we will be using CL of ONE for reads + writes and the dataset we will be using will be quite small.

The issues I can think of now is:

- Any future change that requires a QUORUM read / write will not be performant
- Read repairs may become a problem
- Repairs involve every node in the cluster

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have.  The first cluster that I worked on (Cassandra 0.8 and later 1.1) had 5 nodes in each DC, with a replication factor (RF) of 5 in each.

**tl;dr;**

- We ran with RF == number of nodes ***because it was 2012 and we didn't know any better.***
- RF == 3 is the standard, and anyone using more than that should have a *really* good reason for doing so, AND be able to articulate any advantages that they are getting.

We did see issues with everything you mentioned (repairs, (local) quorum-based queries, etc).  Repair was run as a cron job on the weekend.  So was compaction.  They would often run through Monday morning.

Aside from repairs, disk space was problematic for us (which is why we were manually running compaction...don't EVER run compaction manually).  Garbage collection was also an issue.

Running with RF == number of nodes increases your overall disk footprint.  Especially when you consider that you really don't need to build a keyspace with RF > 3 in each DC.  If a single copy of all of your data is 1 TB, running with RF == number of nodes on a 6 node cluster puts your overall footprint at 6 TB.  That's 3 TB more than you really need.

In fact, if you run a 6 node cluster, where a single copy of your data is 1 TB, and build it using a RF of 3; you've now gone from 1 TB per node down to 500 GB per/node.  If you're using AWS EC2 (Provisioned IOPS) SSDs that's a savings of about $400 USD per month (for just that cluster).  Not sure if $400/month is a big deal to your employer or not, but that adds up.

*In a 30 node cluster, RF==30 vs. RF==3 is a difference of $3400 per month.*

Consider the extra time you're going to spend in bootstrapping a new node or replacing a node.  Newer versions of Cassandra are a little smarter around which nodes participate in this process, but it's going to take so much longer than it needs to.

With RF == number of nodes, each individual node is responsible for all of the data.  That's going to lead to more activity on the Java heap, and ultimately trigger garbage collection to run more often.  Garbage collection was another issue we ran into.  Make each node responsible for a fraction of the data, and ultimately your heap won't thrash as much.

I've literally built *hundreds* of Cassandra clusters since that time.  Every single one ran with a RF of 3, and we never had problems because of that.  Some of those clusters had > 100 nodes per DC.  RF of 3 is really all you need.

*Tip: One thing I learned later on, is that Cassandra runs MUCH better if you have many small nodes, as opposed to a few large nodes.*

TBH our disk space issues were more related to the fact that we did way too many deletes on a few tables, and ended up with lots of tombstones.  Remember, tombstones and in-place updates will artificially inflate your disk footprint and slow down query times.  Sometimes by a lot.  But we would have had some more breathing room on the disks, had we simply just not been storing 5 copies of everything.

Cost calculations were done using the [AWS Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/addService/EC2).